# How can two matrices cancel each other out when there is a matrix in between?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices, gram-schmidt

I'm watching videos of Gilbert Strang's linear algebra lectures. In lecture 17, where he goes over orthonormal bases and the Gram-Schmidt process, he proves

$$ A^TB = A^T\left( b - \frac{A^Tb} {(A^TA)} A\right) = 0 $$

by having

$$ A^T \frac{A^Tb} {(A^TA)} A $$ cancel out into A<sup>T</sup>b. I don't know how the A<sup>T</sup>A on the top was allowed to cancel out with the A<sup>T</sup>A on the bottom if there is an A<sup>T</sup>b sandwiched in between the A<sup>T</sup> and the A on the numerator. Shouldn't the A<sup>T</sup> and the A on the numerator not be allowed to multiply each other?

I wondered if the A<sup>T</sup> on the numerator can cancel out with the A<sup>T</sup> on the denominator and the same for the two A's, but I do not know if this violates the order of operations for matrix multiplication. If I were to write (A<sup>T</sup>A)<sup>-1</sup> rather than have the (A<sup>T</sup>A) on the denominator below the (A<sup>T</sup>b), where would it go?

Comment: Dividing by matrices is completely insane (undefined) in every context I'm aware of, FYI. It might be a misunderstanding. Are we sure these are not dot products, or something of that nature?

Comment: I believe the (A^T)A on the denominator is also interpreted as  (A^T)A inverse.

Comment: The term on the right doesn’t look right for another reason: If $A$ is a matrix and $b$ a column vector the product $bA$ doesn’t make much sense, either. Also, are $B$ and $b$ meant to be the same object? I’m with @TheCount: if this is about the Gram-Schmidt process, then all of the variables in your question are likely vectors. If so, then $A^TA$ is a scalar (well, a $1\times1$ matrix, which you can treat as a scalar most of the time), so you can move it around and divide by it all you like.

Comment: @eriche the problem with that interpretation is that it doesn't specify if the inverse is supposed to be on the right or on the left of the expression:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's Prof. Strang's blackboard at [33m56s](https://youtu.be/uNsCkP9mgRk?t=33m56s):

[image]

Note that $\mathrm A, \mathrm B$ are **vectors**, not matrices!! In other words, the question makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Unconventional notation, to say the least! Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Ohh, thank you so much. I let the notation confuse me into thinking A and B were matrices!